# Document requirements for South Korean Visa e-form

Tags: visas, south-korea

While filling up the e-form for South Korean visa, I noticed that there was no place to upload passport scanned files. However instructions before filling e-form mentioned it:

https://www.visa.go.kr/openPage.do?MENU_ID=10204

There is no helpline number in India for South Korean visa, so I am not sure if I am missing anything.

I did notice "**Reset Passport Reader**" link on e-form but all it does is reset the form when clicked.

Any input or ideas about this will be helpful.

[image]

Comment: I suppose those documents are to be submitted at your appointment, like the US DS forms